# What taxonomy for variables do you use?

Tags: java, .net, eclipse, visual-studio-2010

I'd seen in old codes variables written with its datatype like:

```
double dblMyVar;
int intYourVar;
String strTheirVar;
```

But, nowadays, it seems to be old-fashioned. The advantages of this approach is that you can instantly see the type of a certain variable everywhere it is. But I do dislike long variable names. Whenever I can I name my variables in a single char, like:

```
   private Product p = new Product();
```

There's a modern "good practice" or convention for naming variables? What do/does you/your company use?

Comment: Each language/framework tends to have it's own conventions. For example, [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) and [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, consult the Java Language Specification (JLS). Here's the section regarding [Naming Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.8).

Answer (score 1):

```
// class member only if needed
private Product product;
// instantiates before using it
product = new Product();
```

Declaring the variable type in the name is pretty useless, as the IDE will show you its type on mouse-over. However, using single char names can be pretty confusing for other developers  (specially if you have tons of variables) and goes against the self-documenting principle.

Comment: that's a good point, but, specially when you're doing the persistence (when you must to repeat the field names in the properties and tables), long names could be slower and boring to code.

Comment: @darth_alexious That depends on how you do your persistence. It might be a valid point if you are doing everything manually, even though remembering `var s` or `var something` for me is the same, but if you use Hibernate/JPA/any other it makes pretty much no difference.

Comment: That's true. I have to use Hibernate in my projects, but, for while, its too small to be worth.

Comment: It should be noted though that the original hungarian notation wasn't about what type the variable has, but about additional semantic meaning: Say "this integer is an offset" and so on. But the paper is probably one of the most misunderstood at all.. and MS certainly is to blame for that~

Answer (score 1):

This notation is called "Hungarian" and was popularized by Microsoft, use it if it works for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Comment: Great! I didn't know that this practice has an history and an theory behind... very interesting...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language.

About C#:

- As it's a strongly typed language, adding the type of the variable as a prefix of the name of the variable (Hungarian notation) is not recommended anymore (too much verbosity and redundant information)
- Starting variable names that are public with an upper case is a convention (for instance `MyVariable`): **pascal case**
- Starting variable names that are private with a lower case (or an underscore then a lower case) is a convention too. Using underscore or not is a matter of personal preferences (for example: `_myVariable` or `myVariable`): **camel case**
- Naming temporary variables (such as the variable used in a for loop) with a single letter (`i`, `j`, `z`...) is generally OK if the usage is limited to a small scope.

But it's all about personal preferences.

EDIT: [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

y_xName, y is l/m/p/s for local/member/parameter/static. x could be i for int, f for float, p for pointer, etc.. Perhaps sp for shared pointer.. Rarely anything for most types of object/references.. I prefer code to be self explanatory, hence no names like just "p" or "m_p". Say what it is. If it's a short snippet where it's really just a generic "product" of some sort I might name it l_Product for instance. I see no point in making tiny code, even if you're trying to stay withing 76(?) characters line width, breaking the line at a proper place then indenting can make it look alright and you still see from the verbose names what is actually happening.

Well that's just my take on it..

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I find bit boring to use a name like "PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);" and use [preparedStatement] everywhere... I prefer anithing like p or pst, also to make it more readable...

Answer (score 0):

The only time you should be using "single letter variables" is within a very short piece of code, such as "foreach(var i in item)" or "using(var p = new Product())". Of course that comes down to your own preference, but there's a very nifty little addon for Visual Studio called StyleCop. It has a whole lot of styling checks for pretty much everything, and coupled with ReSharper it can do it real time and even fix things for you.